# datatables saving selected state after table redraw

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using rowcallback to show previously selected rows in the table after redraw... nothing is happening.  I have confirmed in the console that my 'selected' array is correct, but the callback doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Selected stores the tr's id value in its array... on callback if the rows value is in that array the classes should be applied to it.

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/custom/data-tables/process.php",
    // set timestamp as initial sorting
    "aaSorting": [[5,'desc']],
    // change index column
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "searchable": false,
            "sortable": false,
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="'+data+'" />';
            }
        }
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        $('#sample_1 .checkboxes, #sample_1 .group-checkable').uniform();
    },
    "rowCallback": function( row, data, displayIndex ) {
        if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
            $(row).addClass('active selected');
        }
    }
});



var selected = [];

$('#sample_1_wrapper').on('change', 'tbody tr .checkboxes', function () {

    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr("id");
    console.log('id '+id);
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
    console.log('index '+index);


    if ( index === -1 ) {
        selected.push( id );
    }
    else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
    }
    console.log('selected '+selected);
    // add checked status and 
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

    if (checked) {
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active selected");
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active selected");
    }               
});
```

**More info**

Using the console log in the rowCallback before the if statement returns these values :

console.log(data.DT_RowId);
console.log(selected);

187413
["187413"]

So, 187413 is in the selected array so why is it not returning the correct response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had t convert to a string - if ( $.inArray((data.DT_RowId).toString(), selected) > -1 ) {